# invalid operands to binary + (have 'struct student' and 'int')

Tags: c, function, struct, malloc, structure

I am trying to return a structure variable from the function, i created a function getInformation to get the data but i got an error said "**Invalid operands to binary + (have 'struct student' and 'int')"**, What does it mean? and how can i fix it?

```
 int main(){
 struct student *s1;
 int n;
 
printf("Enter how many data: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
 
s1 =(struct student *) malloc(n *sizeof(struct student));  

if ( s1 == NULL) 
{
    printf("memory not available");
    return 1; // exit(1); stlib.h
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    printf("\nEnter details of student %d\n\n", i+1);
     *s1 = getInformation();
}

}
    
struct student getInformation(struct student *s1,int i)   
{   
  struct student s;

    scanf("%d", (s+i)->age);    

    printf("Enter marks: ");
    scanf("%f", (s+i)->marks);

  return s;
}
```

Here is my structure

```
struct student {                                                    
int age;
float marks; 
};
```

Comment: `(s+i)->age` this seems to be wrong because `s` is a structure not a pointer as is `s1`. You should probably use `s1` instead but, in that case, the role of `s` is unclear...

Comment: Function call and function definition are different. Function call doesn't have any arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for error :`scanf("%d",(s+i)->age);`. Here, `s` is not a pointer to structure. So, adding `i` gives you error, because both `s` and `i` are of different types ( `s` is of type `struct student`  but `i` is of type `int`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct student
{
    int age;
    float marks;
};

struct student getInformation(struct student *s1);

int main()
{
    struct student *s1;
    int n;

    printf("Enter how many data: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    s1 = malloc(n * sizeof(struct student));

    if (s1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory not available");
        return 1; // exit(1); stlib.h
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter details of student %d\n\n", i + 1);
        *(s1+i) = getInformation(s1+i); //Changed the function call
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",s1[i].age);
        printf("%f ",s1[i].marks);

    }
}

struct student getInformation(struct student *s1)
{
    
    scanf("%d", &(s1->age));

    printf("Enter marks: ");
    scanf("%f", &(s1->marks));

    return *s1;
}
```

The output is :

```
Enter how many data: 3

Enter details of student 1

23
Enter marks: 67

Enter details of student 2

34
Enter marks: 99

Enter details of student 3

24
Enter marks: 56
23 67.000000 34 99.000000 24 56.000000
```